# Why does :nth-child() select non-existing children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to render a table like this:

```
Header1 | Header2 Header3
-------------------------
Text1   | Text2   Text3
Text1   | Text2   Text3
Text1   | Text2   Text3
Text1   | Text2   Text3
-------------------------
Text1   | Text2   Text3
Text1   | Text2   Text3
Text1   | Text2   Text3
Text1   | Text2   Text3
```

The first four lines (not counting the header) always exist. The last fourth line are optional. If they are not present, the separator line shouldn't be drawn as well.

My first idea was to use this CSS selector:

```
.mytable tr:nth-child(6) > td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

In theory, if the 6<sup>th</sup> line exists, the selector would select it and draw a line (a border) above it. If it does not exist, there is nothing to select in the first place.

But in reality, the border is drawn even if I use 9 as the value for `:nth-child()` selector. With the value of 10, the borders ceases being drawn. This is true even if I edit the table to contain only the first six lines (and set `:nth-child()` to nine).

What is the reason for such strange behavior. Are there any ways to get around it?

**Edit:**
Including the HTML (Mako) code as requested. It's more complicated, but it can be basically reduced to this:

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Text1</th>
        <td>Text2</td>
        <td>Text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Text1</th>
        <td>Text2</td>
        <td>Text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Text1</th>
        <td>Text2</td>
        <td>Text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Text1</th>
        <td>Text2</td>
        <td>Text3</td>
    </tr>

    % for index in range(4):
        <tr>
            <th>Text1</th>

            % for text in texts:
                <td>${text}</td>
            % endfor
        </tr>
    % endfor
</table>
```

Comment: Could you post your html code? [I created a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ys8f375/3/), but it works.

Comment: or `thead` specifically.

Comment: Use `<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>` and `<tbody><tr><th></th></tr></tbody>` for better reading

Comment: Oh, the problem was in the generating code. I overlooked that it generated some 'fantom' lines (empty td's). Thank you for your suggestions.